# How can I output HTML5, that has responsive images, using picture elements with srcset attributes, from Asciidoc source?

Tags: html, srcset, asciidoc, asciidoctor

So, if I wanted HTML5 output that looked like this:

```html
<picture>
  <source type="image/svg+xml" srcset="pyramid.svg">
  <source type="image/webp" srcset="pyramid.webp">
  <img src="pyramid.png" alt="regular pyramid built from four equilateral triangles">
</picture>
```

(taken from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images))

What would my AsciiDoc source look like? Maybe a figure, with multiple images, which is transformed to this using a custom backend, or something? Is this even possible to do using AsciiDoc/Asciidoctor?

Answer (score 3):

It's definitely possible!
Using the built-in `image` macro, you could define something like:

```
image::pyramid.png[regular pyramid built from four equilateral triangles,sources="pyramid.svg,pyramid.webp"]
```

Please note that the `sources` attribute will be available on the `Image` block.

Then, using a custom converter, you could retrieve the value of this attribute to build `<source>` elements (wrapped in a `<picture>` element).
Here's a *simplified* example:

```rb
MIME_TYPES = {
  ".svg" => 'image/svg+xml',
  ".webp" => 'image/webp'
}

def convert_image node
  target = node.attr 'target'
  sources = (node.attr 'sources', '').split(',').map do |src|
    %(<source type="#{MIME_TYPES[File.extname src]}" srcset="#{src}">)
  end
  %(<picture>
#{sources.join("\n")}
<img src="#{target}" alt="#{node.alt}">
</picture>)
end
```

You can certainly do more advanced stuff using additional attributes.

Keep in mind that it's also possible to extend the AsciiDoc syntax using extensions.
Having said that, in this case, I think it's better to use the built-in `image` macro to preserve semantic information.